# Пути к файлам для Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, java-ee, servlet, thymeleaf

Я хочу подключить Bootstrap к моим thymeleaf шаблонам используя локальные файлы, в java servlet приложении (без Spring).
Загвоздка в том, что при PREVIEW (внутри IDEA) страница грузится нормально, ожидаемо, применяя стили.
Но при запуске на localhost (в Tomcat9) стили не применяются.
На скриншоте ниже видна структура папок, и как я пытаюсь подключить пути.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `th:href = @{css/bootstrap.min.css}`

Comment: нет, это не помогает

Answer (score 0):

папка static должна быть в webapp, подключение как на скрине ниже - рабочее 100%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]